# unique constraint to a foreign table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, experiment and sample. Samples must be unique within experiments of the same type, but can be shared between experiments that have a different type. I understand how I can add a unique constraint to the samples to make them always unique, but is it possible to create a unique constraint based on the information in the foreign table?

```
create table experiment (
id integer primary key,
name text,
type text
);

create table sample (
id integer primary key,
name text,
experiment_id integer,
);
alter table sample add constraint exp_fkey foreign key (experiment_id) references experiment(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a (redundant) unique constraint on `experiment (id, type)`, add `type` to `sample`, create a foreign key constraint from `(experiment_id, type)` to `(id, type)` and a unique constraint on `sample.type`.